# How to satisfy extends type interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, typescript-types

Hi I want to make reusable hooks for api request
Here is my code:

```
interface DataResponse<Data> {
  data: Data[];
}

export const useRequestInfiniteHooks = <T extends DataResponse<T>>() => {
  const url = "/lms/class/all";

  const result = apiRequest()
  const mappedData: T['data'] = mappingData()

  return {data: mappedData};
};

type ClassesResponse = {
  data: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
  }[];
  total: number;
};

const MantapComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useRequestInfiniteHooks<ClassesResponse>();
};
```

I want the data to contain the type that passed to generic call which is .
It does already get the type but when i called this hooks it not satisfied.

Here is the error response

[image: hook call]

```
Type 'ClassesResponse' does not satisfy the constraint 'DataResponse<ClassesResponse>'.
  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id: string; title: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ClassesResponse[]'.
      Type '{ id: string; title: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ClassesResponse': data, totalts(2344)
type ClassesResponse = {
    data: {
        id: string;
        title: string;
    }[];
    total: number;
}
```

What should i do to satisfied this hooks call ?

I try to call it like this but still got the error

[image]

```
Type 'DataResponse<ClassesResponse>' does not satisfy the constraint 'DataResponse<DataResponse<ClassesResponse>>'.
  Type 'ClassesResponse' is not assignable to type 'DataResponse<ClassesResponse>'.
    Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
      Type 'Class[]' is not assignable to type 'ClassesResponse[]'.
        Type 'Class' is missing the following properties from type 'ClassesResponse': data, totalts(2344)
type ClassesResponse = {
    data: Class[];
    total: number;
}
```

I have read the documentation here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

They only told you how to make the function with generic but not how to call it properly to make it satisfied with the type you passed.

So that's my question how to satisifed that hook/function call?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `useRequestInfiniteHooks<DataResponse<ClassesResponse>>()`?

Comment: i have tried that. it still didn't satisfied. i have updated my question on that way call and the error that i got

Comment: I think it is because you have a kind of self-referential (maybe infinite?) generic constraint. It should probably be something like: `useRequestInfiniteHooks = <T extends DataResponse<any>>()`. Either that or an Interface that `DataResponse` estends instead of `any`.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to indicate how you can use Data as a generic type in the call.

Answer (score 0):

You have a kind of self-referential (maybe infinite?) generic constraint. You also need to make your `ClassesResponse` extend from `DataResponse`. The below could work:

```ts
interface IData {
  id: string
}

interface IDataResponse<IData> {
  data: IData[]
}

export const useRequestInfiniteHooks = <T extends IDataResponse<IData>>() => {
  const url = "/lms/class/all"

  const result = apiRequest()
  const mappedData: T['data'] = mappingData()

  return { data: mappedData }
};

class ClassesResponse implements IDataResponse<Data> {
  data: Data[];
  total: number
}

class Data implements IData {
  id: string
  title: string
}

const MantapComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useRequestInfiniteHooks<ClassesResponse>()
}
```

Comment: still don't get it. why do you have to use class?

Comment: I've never really used `type`. It looks like it is an an alias more than anything else. See [https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases ](Documentation for type alias). Nonetheless, you could define `Data` using `type` - e.g. `type Data = { id: string ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to look up the `data` type of the generic type `T`.

The generic parameter of `DataResponse` is `Data`, NOT `T`.

```
interface DataResponse<Data> {
  data: Data[];
}

export const useRequestInfiniteHooks = <T extends DataResponse<T['data'][0]>>() => {
  const url = "/lms/class/all";
  return {data: {}};
};

type ClassesResponse = {
  data: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
  }[];
  total: number;
};

const MantapComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useRequestInfiniteHooks<ClassesResponse>();
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAShAzgBwHsRcIAedTAPmQG8AoZZAEwzgC402BtAXQG56AX3r0IADyJQwyBMVwyArqRwBHRXjABJEDFDBIACUKEA1rmQBeZGQAqyCZBDMLlbHiIlyt7gHJWmL683AAMvFRUABQAlFY0DExyJEpQADZWyABEAPSpALa42QipcLiFcKmpmYJMUBBgilAgdAEcdEJCgp2iYACe+CgAwiVleDgE8ijWCSxsnDNMwMycClCgAOY1TMhgBqkQK2BrIJuMyEJ8W2CEmKmcIIp5AEbQXYL0SQrIALJw4HD4QaEPKeCDgDIxOJ0M6fGS0WaYc4ZZQQNQaBQ6PQgAwQYxmXBkYalUi4caeUhRaJvIA)